# foreach Loop Not Working With Object

Tags: php, object, foreach

I have an object called `entry`. I want to access a `MySQL` database and pull the relevant information for the object entry. These are my pages:

**objects.php**

```
class main {
    function setValues( $rs = array() ){
        foreach( $rs as $key => $val ){
            $this->$key = $val ;
        }
    }

    var $created ;
    var $updated ;
}

class entry extends main {
    var $id ;
    var $channel ;

    var $title ;
    var $content ;
}
$table_names['entry'] = 'archive' ;
```

**functions.php**

```
$dbconn = mysqli_connect( DB_HOST , DB_USER , DB_PASS , DB_NAME ) ;
$table_names = array() ;

function getTableValues( $object ){
    global $table_names ;
    $table_name = $table_names[ get_class( $object ) ] ;

    $r = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table_name ;
    return $r ;
}

function query( $q ){
    global $dbconn ;
    $stmt = mysqli_query( $dbconn , $q ) ;

    return $stmt ;
}

function fetchRow( $stmt ){
    return mysqli_fetch_array( $stmt , MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ;
}

function find( $object , $other = '' , $orderBy = '' ){
    global $dbconn ;
    $list = array() ;
    $q = getTableValues( $object ) ;

    $q .= $other.' '.$orderBy ;     
    $stmt = query( $q ) ;
    $objectClass = get_class( $object ) ;
    while( $rv = fetchRow( $stmt ) ){
        $obj = new $objectClass() ;
        $obj->setValues( $rv ) ;
        $list = $obj ;      
    }

    return $list ;
}
```

Then, on the actual page I have

```
<?php
    require_once( '../lib/functions.php' ) ;    
    require_once( '../lib/objects.php' ) ;

    $entries = find( new entry() ) ;
?>

<?php
    foreach($entries as $entry){
?>      
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $entry->id ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $entry->channel ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $entry->title ?></td>
        <td><a href='' class='button'>Edit</a>&nbsp;<a href='' class='button'>View</a></td>
    </tr>
<?php
    }    
?>
```

I end up getting the error:

```
Trying to get property of a non-object
```

as a result of the `foreach` loop and it iterates this eight times even though right now there's only one entry for testing purposes. Using the `foreach` loop with only `$entries`, it properly pulled information but, again, iterated eight times. I'm pretty sure this is because there are eight columns in the SQL table, but I don't know why it would be doing this.

I also used used echo to make sure the SQL statements were correct, used count to make sure there was only one item in the arrays that were a result of the executed functions (there was) and used `print_r()` to print out the information stored in `$entries` (it was all correct). So, it seems to me that the reason this isn't working is because of the `foreach` loop. But I do not know why this is or how to fix it.

Any and all help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `$table_names` is global variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your `find` function to:

```
function find( $object , $other = '' , $orderBy = '' ){
    global $dbconn ;
    $list = array() ;
    $q = getTableValues( $object ) ;

    $q .= $other.' '.$orderBy ;     
    $stmt = query( $q ) ;
    $objectClass = get_class( $object ) ;
    while( $rv = fetchRow( $stmt ) ){
        $obj = new $objectClass() ;
        $obj->setValues( $rv ) ;
        $list[] = $obj ;  // earlier you were looping through columns, now it will loop through rows      
    }

    return $list ;
}
```

Comment: In your `foreach` loop you are iterating columns/fields. I corrected the code of `find` function to fix it.